# Logging user activities in applications

Tags: php, mysql, database, web-applications

The problem I'm here to talk about and (ask about of course) is not new. I searched web and stack overflow and I got ideas to many part of this problem (pros and cons) but there is still some part missing in my mind. So I thought it would be a good idea to share in one place (of course it will be more complete with others' ideas) and ask for it.

The problem is clear: **"We Want to log every single action of user"** - probably when we solve the big problem, smaller ones (like logging only one action would be piece of cake).

First from what I read over the web and stack overflow:

**Use DB instead of File:** That's a good advice although it always depends on situation. But because of many benefits of DB, in long term and in general, it's the better solution.

**DB Layer or Application Layer:** Actually it depends. For example If you want really monitor everything(I mean really every single rows that changes in Database, it seems we will have one choice *"Using Database Triggers"*. Although there are many discussions around MySQL that says, triggers slowdown DB and they advised not to use it. So it depends on the level of details you need, you can put your logging system in **DB Layer** or **Application Layer**(for exam some common function call $logClass->logThis()).

**Use Observers:** Clean codes are always better. If you are familiar with observers, you can use them to do things for you when an action is happened so you don't have to add *$logClass->logThis()* every time a CRUD happens in your application.

**What To Log:** Simple and short answer is: *Based on your needs*, but there are some common fields you will need:

- user_id (*if a unique user ID is available*)
- timestamp (*unix maybe*)
- ip (*not everyone know how to fake it in first place so use it, even faking it give you some insight about user behavior*)
- action_id (*should be predefined actions for better unifying in queries and reports*)
- object_id (*the unique row ID of a record that changes had made on*)
- action (***which my question is about this part***)
- and etc...

I would appreciate if anyone correct me if I made mistake in any part or add other useful information to this post, so it would become one of good references for other users.

And now my question: **How to Store actions?**. For better understanding, consider following scenario.

I have a table named "product" and a table named "companies". From the business logic we want to assign products to companies, which we ended up in a table "company_product". Now when a user insert new product and simultaneously assign it's companies, 2 table will be affected (the same goes for delete and update): "product" and "company_product" and we want to know:

- what's inserted?
- what's deleted?
- what's updated to what?

For performance issue and because I don't have enough knowledge about triggers, I want to use logging in Application Layer, so I ended up with this idea that I can, save **action fields of database** in **array** or **json** structure. But as I developed my solution I encountered a problem: **How to make this log understandable for non technical users?** Because for example I want to save something like this in action field of database when delete(insert) product with id 20:

```
action : [{id: 20, product_id:2, company_id: 1},{id: 21, product_id:2, company_id: 2}]
```

And this is not something easy for every one to read and understand. Actually I can use this json more readable and make it something like this:

```
action : {'Product A Deleted From Company X', 'Product A Deleted From Company Y'}
```

and save the previous action in technical_action field for further diagnose, But it needs additional works and more query to run for something that is not always needed to be considered(log)

I would appreciate any additional information on this article (I'm definitely sure that there exist other criteria that can be discussed), and answer to my question.

Comment: Please make comment on -1 on the post so I know what is wrong with the post or the content. thanks :)

Comment: I was wondering is this subject so obvious for everyone, or we don't consider logging in our projects?? 2 days and no participation from community!

Answer (score 0):

You are actually going to gather details for analytics kind of stuffs. 
It will be good if you go for flat tables rather than going to relational tables.

Because if you want to do more analysis your relational table will not be a good choice as it lacks in performance.

Comment: The log table is flat, relation between example tables of product and company was relational that actually is irrelevant to discussion and considered as an example. If you mean Flat Databases like NoSQL variants, it can be discussed seperately